# Add link to customer menu after another

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

I followed these two guides: [one](http://inchoo.net/magento/managing-navigation-links/), [two](http://www.riccardobianconi.it/en/tutorials/edit-links-inside-magento-account-page/)
but I can't add my link at the end of the others, and maybe it's because there's an extension that put their own.

I don't know how Magento construct the layout if it has an order or something.

In `customer.xml` after the Magento default links, I tried to add mine but after the extension ones (with `after="extensionLinkName"`). And it doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `local.xml` file is loaded last when rendering layout xml, so that would likely be the best place, if you want your links to be at the end.  There is an SE question [HERE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/41624/33071) with a great deal more information on the order that Magento constructs its layout.

As for an immediate solution, you'll want to place the following **at the end of your app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/layout/local.xml file:**

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="left">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label">
            <name>some_link_name</name>
            <path>the/path/wanted/</path>
            <label>Link Label</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

If for some reason (likely explained in the referenced link) your extension is being loaded after the local.xml file, then you'll have to copy the appropriate layout file to your fallback theme and insert the `addLink` action in the appropriate spot.

Comment: Thanks, It's work perfectly, I did not know that the layout load follow an order