# Add link to customer-menu

Tags: magento2, customer, menu, toplinks

I need to add a custom link to the dropdown menu :

```
        <div class="customer-menu" data-target="dropdown">
```

How can I do this easily (without using jquery), I need to do it the magento way

Comment: For magento version are you referring ? If this is for magento 1 , had you tried this fix https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200333/add-link-to-customer-menu-after-another ?

Comment: As my tag says, it's for magento 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create/copy a **default.xml** file and add your custom link there.

If your current/parent theme is Luma, use the **top.links**.

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="my-custom-contact-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Contact</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">contact</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

If your current/parent theme is Blank, use the **header.links**.

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="my-custom-contact-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Contact</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">contact</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done 2mins ago, this is it. Thanks !